# Access OAuth response in a custom policy

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-oauth2

According [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-claim-elements), if I need include external idp token in a response, I need this code:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Are there any explanations about such syntax - `PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}"`? What else can I reference except `access_token, refresh_token`? How "object structure" for `oauth2` looks like? Does only `oauth2` available, or something else also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you can use are documented in the page about [claim resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview).

For your case, check the section: [OAuth2 identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2-identity-provider).
It lists the available options as:

- {oauth2:access_token}
- {oauth2:token_type}
- {oauth2:expires_in}
- {oauth2:refresh_token}